# Multithreading: incorrect change value

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I create n independent threads, after the transaction method is executed, the values ​​must change (money must go from one account to another), but after execution, the values ​​do not change. By default, in the save method I add 10000 to each account. 9 transactions should occur and after that the program should terminate.

Entity Account:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Account {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter
    private long id;

    @Column(name= "money")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int money;

    public static AtomicInteger numberTransaction = new AtomicInteger();

    public int withdrawal(int value) {
       return money += value;
    }

    public int send(int value) {
       return money -= value;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class AccountService extends Thread {
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public AccountService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Account> findAllAccount() {
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Account save(Account account) {
        account.setMoney(10000);
        return accountRepository.save(account);
    }

    public Long countAccount() {
        return accountRepository.count();
    }

    public Account update(Account category) {
        return accountRepository.save(category);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        accountRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void transaction(Long accountIdOne, Long accountIdTwo, int value) {
        Account accountOne = accountRepository.findById(accountIdOne).orElseThrow();
        Account accountTwo = accountRepository.findById(accountIdTwo).orElseThrow();
        lock.lock();
        try {
            accountOne.withdrawal(value);
            this.update(accountOne);
            accountTwo.send(value);
            this.update(accountTwo);
            Account.numberTransaction.incrementAndGet();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }


    }

    public void test() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (Account.numberTransaction.get() < 10) {
                    int sleep = (int) (Math.random() * (2000 - 1000)) + 1000;
                    try {
                        transaction(1L, 2L, 1000);
                        Thread.sleep(sleep);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void contextLoads() throws InterruptedException {
    Account account = new Account();
    Account account1 = new Account();

    accountService.save(account);
    accountService.save(account1);

    for(int i = 0; i < accountService.countAccount(); i++) {
        accountService.test();
        accountService.join();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think your synchronised blocks are doing here? Put another way, where does the instance of `Account` come from?

Comment: I also see `Account.numberTransaction++` which is not a thread safe call.

Comment: What requirement does your synchronisation scheme place on `accountRepository.findById`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I take these values ​​from the database and i lock monitor

Comment: @tgdavies what's wrong with taking data from the database?

Comment: What does synchronised do exactly? What does that mean `findById` must guarantee for your code to work?

Comment: (and for bonus points: if your code worked correctly, can you see how it can deadlock?)

Comment: @tgdavies synchronised my two account. Why not? i get a full fledged object from my database

Comment: @tgdavies my code only works correctly in one thread

Answer (score 1):

If we run the following code:

```
Account accountOneA = accountRepository.findById(1L).orElseThrow();
Account accountOneB = accountRepository.findById(1L).orElseThrow();
```

We expect that `accountOneA.equals(accountOneB)` will be true, assuming that `Account` has a sensible `equals()` implementation.

We *don't* expect that `accountOneA == accountOneB` will be true, because `AccountRepository` will be creating a new object for the result of each query. We want this behaviour for thread safety, as two transactions might modify the data in different ways, to be reconciled when they try to save it.

The `synchronized` keyword locks a *particular Object*, so for it to work, each thread must be synchronising using the same instance.

That's why your synchronisation doesn't work.

If `findById` *did* return the same instance for the same id, your code would be prone to deadlock. Imagine that one thread is transferring from account 1 to account 2, while another thread is doing the reverse, transferring from 2 to 1:

1. Thread one locks account 1
2. Thread two locks account 2
3. Thread one tries to lock account 2, can't and waits
4. Thread two tries to lock account1, can't and waits

Now both threads are waiting forever.

You could avoid this problem by sorting all the account numbers which are going to be locked in a given transaction, and always locking them in that order.

Comment: Interesting reasoning, but i don't understand, how is this related in this situation, please give an example

Comment: @Saintka I'm not sure which part you don't understand: that `findById` may return a different object for the same id, or that synchronising on the same object for the same id is important.

Comment: How can a method return a different object one by one id? Yes, sthat synchronising on the same object for the same id is important.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you aren't testing a multithread scenario.

You have one thread that is accessing everything one after each other. From the question I assume that this is not your intention.

What I also like is using a locker object of type ReentrantLock(). Then you have a single instance of the object and lock it before the synchronized code block and you can unlock it when the work is done.

Like in the following example (taken and adapted from https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/):

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

void transaction(Long accountIdOne, Long accountIdTwo, int value) {
    Account accountOne = accountRepository.findById(accountIdOne).orElseThrow();
    Account accountTwo = accountRepository.findById(accountIdTwo).orElseThrow();

    lock.lock();
    try {
        accountOne.withdrawal(value);
        this.update(accountOne);
        accountTwo.send(value);
        this.update(accountTwo);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saintka I saw in your edited question that for a withdrawal you are doing money += value. Is this right? Usually on withdrawal you remove money from your account.

Further question, what is your test assertion? From your code I currently can't see what you are validating to see if your logic worked or not. Something like account.getMoney().equals(1000); or so.

Comment: I am using the DB interface to validate the logic, i see that using transaction, money don’t edit

Comment: What you could try is to use saveAndFlush() instead of save() on the repository. It instantly brings the changes to the database.

Comment: It did not help